# I have used write bean tag in jsp file but when i try to create output stream using response object then it gives IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have used write bean tag in jsp file but when i try to create output stream using response object then it gives IllegalStateException.

What is the solution to create output stream and run the code correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ServletReponse` object provides two methods, `getWriter` to output text data, and `getOutputStream` to output binary data.

Only one of them can be called, otherwise an IllegalStateException is thrown.

In a JSP, the translated coded calls `getWriter` when needs to output any text, hence the error you are getting.

To call `response.getOutputStream` in a JSP file you have to make sure that no text needs to be written prior to the call, so you have to get rid of all text outside the `<% %>` marks, even `new line` chars between JSP directives.

Comment: I am calling response .getOutputStream() from Action file.

Comment: in jsp file, i am having that write bean tag......and IllegalStateException  is coming in Action java file.....i am unable to attach screenshot of exception here

Comment: If the JSP file performs any write operation before passing the response to the Action object, that object cannot call `getOutputStream` because the JSP file internally has already called `getWriter`.

Comment: You either need to use `getWriter` in your Action object instead of `getOutputStream`, or, if you really need to output binary data in your Action object you will need to make sure that your JSP doesn't print anything before passing the response to the Action object.

Comment: Then what can i use to display anything on page.